# Can't use System.Configuration.Configuration manager in a .NET Standard2.0 library on .NET FX4.6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have an assembly created in *NetStandard2.0*. It reads AppSettings using **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager**. I have installed nuget package of **System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager** with version 4.4.X which is suitable for *NetStandard2.0*.

When I refer this assembly in console app (.Net Core) it is reading AppSettings properly, but when I refer this assembly in old .NetFramework(4.6.X) console app it is not working and throwing an exception.

Please see the code below.

**Assembly 1: NetStandard 2.0**

**Nuget: System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0**

```
using System.Configuration;

namespace Bootstrapper.Lib
{
   public class Bootstrapper
   {
     public Bootstrapper()
     {

     }

     public void LoadAppSettings()
     {
         string serachPattern= 
         ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssemblySearchPattern"];
     }
  }

}
```

**Console App: NetFx 4.6.X**

```
using System;
using Bootstrapper.Lib;
namespace Bootstrapper.Console
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Bootstrapper().LoadAppSettings();
    }
  }
}
```

**Exception After Run:**

```
'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, 
 Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one 
 of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

It will work with Console App developed using .NetCore.

Please help!!!

Comment: Microsoft has just announced a "Windows Compatibility Pack for .NET Core". That, among other things, contains `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` (but turns your .NET core app "Windows only" in turn). I don't know if it is already available. Just google for the term in quotes and see what you can find out.

Comment: Did you enable automatic binding redirect generation as described in https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/31 ?

Comment: @MartinUllrich Yes, I tried it Today but getting the same exception.

Comment: Solved it!. just added nuget of  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.4.0 to console application

Answer (score 75):

As @kiran mentioned in a comment you can solve this by running:

```
Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
```

in NuGet Package Manager

Comment: @Xander In my case, I installed it in NetFramework(4.6.X) console app.

Comment: You can install this nugget package manager from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/4.6.0-preview6.19303.8 All instructions on how to install it are there. As of this time you will also need to have NETFramework 4.6.1 and above.

Comment: Any idea why this happens? I understand the solution but don't understand which component is declaring dependency on that assembly

Answer (score 16):

It is not possible to create .NET Standard library which references `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package and uses `ConfigurationManager` class. Once library adds reference to .NET Core specific package it ceases to be portable .NET Standard library since it is bound to framework specific package.

`.NET Standard 2.0` does not contain `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` API. Therefore, the only way to use this API is to build one version of the library against .NET Core `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` package which can be used on `.NET Core` and have a second version of the library which is build against .NET FX `System.Configuration` assembly and can be used on `.NET FX`.

Comment: This answer is now outdated and the correct answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/50937932/943435

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue and after installing the same System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager package in the FX4.6 project resolved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative solutions are the following:

**1. Copy .Net Standard dependencies**

Add below line to your .Net Standard csproj file (Assembly 1) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090393/6537984).

`<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>`

Then rebuild Console App and `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll` with other dependencies of Assembly 1 will be copied to bin directory of Console App.

In my case it copies the below list of dlls
[image: Dependencies of .Net Standard]

Interesting thing is that when I use another solution and install System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager NuGet package to FX4.6 Console App directly, I have another set of dependencies in result:
[image: Dependencies of .Net Framework]

Notice that `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll` as well as other dlls have different size. As I understand, in first case it was copied from `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\system.configuration.configurationmanager\5.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0`, but in second case from `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages\system.configuration.configurationmanager\5.0.0\lib\net461`

Anyway, both solutions work, so I'm not sure which is more correct.

or

**2. Use multi-targeting**

In your .Net Standard csproj file (Assembly 1) set second target to net461 as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/library-guidance/cross-platform-targeting) with line

`<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net461</TargetFrameworks>`

Then on build two versions of library will be generated - in `\bin\Release\net461` and in `\bin\Release\netstandard2.0`. If your Console App targets .Net Framework 4.6.1 or higher, it will automatically take correct version of Assembly 1 as dependency (the one from \net461).

The benefit of that approach is that net461 version of library doesn't require dependency from System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.dll and can be distributed without it.