# Is there a way to publish a .NET Standard Library without producing a .nupkg in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, publish, .net-standard

My understanding is that when you publish a .NET Standard Library, the expected behavior is to produce a `.nupkg`.

I have internal .Net Standard libraries that I maintain for use on in-house projects. A typical workflow would be to publish the libraries and then copy the published files to consuming projects. Is this not the way I should be doing things? I'm a bit confused by the lack of options when publishing a .NET Standard Library -- being that there is a `.nupkg` without a choice to publish in a different form.

What I *want* to get from publish is just a collection of necessary library files in the publish directory (not inside a `nupkg`). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There's only one intention of a .nupkg file, to publish it to a Nuget server.  Which is wise, but doesn't sound what you actually want to do.  Putting library files into a dedicated directory doesn't take a .nupkg, you'd simply change the project's output path.  Just make sure you can put it all back together on a new machine five years from now.

Comment: I originally thought all I needed to do was Build the project. But that produced a very unexpected problem that I asked about here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58085571/dlls-from-nuget-packages-are-missing-from-build-folder-in-net-standard-dll-proj This lead me to trying to use Publish (which I'd never used before). But it sounds like Publish isn't the right way to go either.  What is the correct workflow to just build a .net standard DLL and get all the dependencies copied into the build folder so that it can be deployed manually? Is it not publish?

Comment: @JamesHoux Where are you deploying it? What will be consuming the library?

Comment: @NateBarbettini Deploying to an in-house Libs folder that can be used within another Solution and its projects

Comment: I know this might not work with your setup, but FWIW - a project reference is a lot easier than referencing a built DLL (or nupkg) if you are developing multiple projects locally.

Comment: Like Nate suggests, if you develop them locally, you can add project reference to do it. (If not same solution, add existing project first). And if you want to output a folder with several assemblies, and share the folder to others, you may have to do some modify in xx.csproj.  Also as the document in my answer says, `The primary distribution vehicle for the .NET Standard reference assemblies is NuGet packages`, then when you publish it and get a xx.nupkg, for the further development you can share the xx.nupkg(a nuget package) to others easily. It do have some advantages.

Comment: The info about which packages are referenced by the .net standard project is stored in a hidden xx.nuspec file in xx.nupkg. You have no need to unzip it to use the output project.dll, the correct way to share the xx.nupkg to others or other project locally is to consume the xx.nupkg into one project by **Package Manager UI or Package Manager console in VS**, or use [dotnet cli](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-dotnet-cli?view=vsmac-2019) in server.  Since the info about dependencies ID are stored in xx.nupkg, those packages will also be installed .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding is that when you publish a .Net Standard Library, the
>   expected behavior is to produce a .nupkg. What I want to get from
>   publish is just a collection of necessary library files in the publish
>   directory (not inside a nupkg). Is there a way to do this?

For normal .net framework projects, if you reference one nuget package and build it. You then get a output folder(bin\debug or bin\release) with the Project.dll and Package.dll in it. And that's what you want.

But for `.net standard` project, it will only output the `Project.dll` by default. Also it's intended behavior, see [comment1](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/747#issuecomment-276252207), [comment2](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/747#issuecomment-419496825). And that's why I suggest you need to manually edit the `xx.csproj` to get your expected behavior during build. That's by design that it won't copy the nuget dependencies to output, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58090393/10910450) is the workaround that may meet your needs.

As for why the `publish output is a xx.nupkg` when you right-click project node=>Publish in VS IDE(.net standard project), please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#package-representation):***The primary distribution vehicle for the .NET Standard reference assemblies is NuGet packages.***  I assume that's why the output of Publish is a xx.nupkg, hard to say but, it could be by design...

**Edit:**

> Is there a way to publish a .Net Standard Library without producing a
>   .nupkg in Visual Studio 2019?

If you're referring to the **Publish** option for .net standard project.(Right click the project name of .net standard project in Solution Explorer=>Publish). I'm afraid the answer is negative. This option is by design and for now no other options like `publish a folder with all referenced assemblies` are supported. You may need to add a [Feature Request in DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

Hope my clarifications make some help and if I misunderstand anything, feel free to correct me :(

Answer (score 0):

> A typical workflow would be to publish the libraries and then copy the published files to consuming projects. Is this not the way I should be doing things?

No. That's just about the worst way to do things.

If/as you're not using locally generated Nuget packages you should be using [project references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2019#project-to-project-references):

> When you have a project that produces an assembly, you should reference the project and not use a file reference. The advantage of a project-to-project reference is that it creates a dependency between the projects in the build system.

Every solution which contains a project which references one or more of your in-house libraries should also contain the libraries (and any in-house libraries those libraries reference) in the solution.

I'll run through this creating some throwaway projects as I go, but the techniques apply to existing code too - you'd just be adding them to the solution rather than creating new ones:

- Create `ClassLibrary1` targeting .NET Standard 2.0
- Add a new project to the solution: `ClassLibrary2` targeting .NET Standard 2.0
- Let's install a popular Nuget package to `ClassLibrary2`: `Newtonsoft.Json`
- Right click on `ClassLibrary1` in the solution explorer, click `Add` and then click `Reference`. In the project tab tick `ClassLibrary2` and click OK. `ClassLibrary1` now has a project reference to `ClassLibrary2` and the following has been added to `ClassLibrary1.csproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary2\ClassLibrary2.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

- Add a .NET console app project, `ConsoleApp1`
- Add a project reference for `ClassLibrary` to `ConsoleApp1`
- Save the solution
- Build, with a release configuration, the solution
- Everything we need is in the console app's bin folder, and there is no Nupkg folder in sight:

[image]

- If we create another solution and add our libraries to it, or reuse this solution, and then add a .NET Core console app to it, and have that app take a project reference to `ClassLibrary1` and build, again there is no Nupkg anywhere in the folder tree.
- However, we *publish* .NET Core apps. I, at least, like to publish my .NET Core apps (for internal use) as 'self-contained'. To do this, I right click on the .NET Core app in the Solution Explorer, click `Publish`, and choose `Folder` as the target. I click `Create Profile` and then `Edit` and change the deployment mode to `self-contained`, and then save. I then publish the app (***not*** the libraries) and I get all the files I need in my publish folder, including the in-house libraries and .NET Core (don't worry, the Newtonsoft DLL is there too, it's just not visible in the screenshot):

[image]

The only times I get a Nuget package built are:

- if I explicitly publish the in-house libraries, or
- if I have `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` in the project file [[example](https://github.com/kingboyk/Serilog.NodaTime/blob/master/Serilog.NodaTime/Serilog.NodaTime.csproj)]

Doing it the "Nuget way" is a great and valid approach if you're distributing the libraries via a private package feed; but since that's not what you want to do - don't publish the libraries! Take project references to them instead, which means adding the libraries to the solutions which consume them